# Servlet Context Path Empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing weird issue with my spring boot upgrade. In the application.properties file i configured my servlet path to

```
server.servlet.context-path=/somePath

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true

#overriding old spring beans with newer version
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

but when i run my api in the console logs i am seeing context path empty - `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''` I am not sure what am i doing wrong here but i would appreciate any help.

Comment: which version of spring boot you are using

Comment: I am using 2.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Are you sure your `application.properties` is being read at all? Perhaps try overriding a bean to double check? Or add a property that you inject using `@Value("${property.name}")`?

Comment: Well this issue seems to be solved for me when i added this in my pom.xml file  <properties>

  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <applicationVersion>0.1.0</applicationVersion>
  <elasticsearch.version>5.2.0</elasticsearch.version>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

Comment: But now that i am able to see context-path in console when i try to deploy my api i am getting context-path is not normalized error.

Comment: Update - There was an extra slash that was causing normalized error. I fixed it and everything is working now.